# Understanding the universal properties of kernels

Tags: group-theory, category-theory

[image]

I understand why $\bar{\alpha}$ was chosen and how it works just fine, but I don't seem to understand why $\bar{\alpha}$ is unique. Wouldn't the trivial homomorphism $\beta: K \to \ker \varphi$ where $\forall k \in K \ \ \beta(k)=e_G$ work?

Sure, then $\text{im } \beta \subsetneq \ker \varphi$ if $|\varphi^{-1}(e_{G'})|>1$, but we would still have $(\varphi \circ i \circ \beta)(k)=e_{G'}$ for all $k\in K$ just fine still so the diagram commutes, right?'

---

**Edit:** Ahhh wait, thinking more about it, is the problem that then $i \circ \beta \neq \alpha$?

Comment: Perhaps this question could help you understand the property better : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1422987/universal-property-of-kernel-of-a-homomorphism?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that $i\circ \beta\neq a$. It's not explicitly mentioned, but the universal property here says that you can find a unique $\bar{\alpha}$ **such that the diagram commutes**, i.e. such that $\alpha=i\circ \bar{\alpha}$. In this case the uniqueness is pretty easy to see, since $i$ is injective by definition.

Comment: I understood that it had to commute but forgot to look at that portion of the diagram -- thank you for clarifying!